# How to generate with python a service endpoint in azureml for getting probabilities from a classification model? My code fails

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to publish a model in AzureML Studio in a endpoint for getting probabilities results and not binary classes, but I can't publish my model - I'm getting an error and I do not know what I'm doing wrong...

My code:

```
# Step 1: Connect to your Azure ML workspace and load the Titanic dataset:
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

# Connect to your workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()

# Load the Titanic dataset from your workspace
titanic_data = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, name='Titanic_Data')
df = titanic_data.to_pandas_dataframe()

# Step 2: Preprocess and split your data into training and testing sets:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Preprocess your data as needed (remove unnecessary columns, handle missing values, encode categorical variables, etc.)

# Split your data into training and testing sets
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Step 3: Train a classification model (using RandomForest in this example):
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Define features (independent variables) and the target variable (Survived)
X = train_data drop(columns='Survived')
y = train_data['Survived']

# Train a RandomForest model
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

# Step 4: Save the trained model in this notebook's location for later registration in your workspace:
import joblib
from azureml.core.model import Model

# Save the model in pickle format
model_name = 'titanic_model.pkl'
joblib.dump(model, model_name)

# Register the model in your workspace
model = Model.register(workspace=ws, model_path=model_name, model_name='titanic_model')

# Step 5: Define the scoring script (score.py) for the web service. Create it in the same notebook location.

# My score.py:

# Save this code in a file named 'score.py'
import json
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from azureml core model import Model

def init():
    global model
    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name='titanic_model')
    model = joblib.load(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    try:
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        predictions = model.predict_proba(data)
        return json.dumps(predictions.tolist())
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

# Step 6: Define the environment required for the web service:
from azureml core conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml core environment import Environment

# Create a CondaDependencies object to specify required libraries
conda_deps = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['scikit-learn', 'pandas', 'joblib'])

# Create an environment and define the dependencies
myenv = Environment(name='myenv')
myenv.python conda_dependencies = conda_deps

# Step 7: Deploy the model as a web service:
from azureml core webservice import AciWebservice
from azureml core model import InferenceConfig
from azureml core import Model

# Define the web service configuration
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, memory_gb=1)

# Configure the inference environment
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py', environment=myenv)

# Retrieve the trained model
model = Model(ws, id='azureml://locations/switzerlandnorth/workspaces/a1797bf8-77a0-43f6-87a9-b0e1dc442ed0/models/titanic_model/versions/1')

# Deploy the web service
service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws, name='titanic-service', models=[model], inference_config=inference_config, deployment_config=aciconfig)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Error in step7:

```
Received bad response from Model Management Service:
Response Code: None
Correlation: None
Content: None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelErrorResponseException               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/models_client.py:31, in ModelsClient.error_with_model_id_handling.<locals>.wrapper(self, model_id, *args, **kwargs)
     30 try:
---> 31     return func(self, model_id, *args, **kwargs)
     32 except ModelErrorResponseException as ex:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/models_client.py:76, in ModelsClient.get_by_id(self, model_id)
     74 @error_with_model_id_handling
     75 def get_by_id(self, model_id):
---> 76     return self.\
     77         _execute_with_workspace_arguments(self._client.ml_models.query_by_id, model_id,
     78                                           custom_headers=ModelsClient.get_modelmanagement_custom_headers())

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/workspace_client.py:72, in WorkspaceClient._execute_with_workspace_arguments(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
     71 def _execute_with_workspace_arguments(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
---> 72     return self._execute_with_arguments(func, copy.deepcopy(self._workspace_arguments), *args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:590, in ClientBase._execute_with_arguments(self, func, args_list, *args, **kwargs)
    589     else:
--> 590         return self._call_api(func, *args_list, **kwargs)
    591 except ErrorResponseException as e:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:245, in ClientBase._call_api(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    244 else:
--> 245     return self._execute_with_base_arguments(func, *args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:334, in ClientBase._execute_with_base_arguments(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    333 total_retry = 0 if self.retries < 0 else self.retries
--> 334 return ClientBase._execute_func_internal(
    335     back_off, total_retry, self._logger, func, _noop_reset, *args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:368, in ClientBase._execute_func_internal(cls, back_off, total_retry, logger, func, reset_func, *args, **kwargs)
    367 except Exception as error:
--> 368     left_retry = cls._handle_retry(back_off, left_retry, total_retry, error, logger, func)
    370 reset_func(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:427, in ClientBase._handle_retry(cls, back_off, left_retry, total_retry, error, logger, func)
    426     elif error.response.status_code < 500 and error.response.status_code != 408:
--> 427         raise error
    428 elif isinstance(error, ClientRequestError):

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/clientbase.py:359, in ClientBase._execute_func_internal(cls, back_off, total_retry, logger, func, reset_func, *args, **kwargs)
    358 logger.debug("ClientBase: Calling {} with url {}".format(func_name, func_url))
--> 359 response = func(*args, **kwargs)
    360 if (isinstance(response, Response) and cls._is_retryable_status_code(response.status_code)
    361         and left_retry > 0):
    362     # This is the handle the error case 1. response.raise_for_status only throws HTTPError exception.
    363     # if the status_code is retryable and it is not the last retry, then the exception is thrown.
    364     # Otherwise, we will return the response directly.

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/operations/ml_models_operations.py:86, in MLModelsOperations.query_by_id(self, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace, id, custom_headers, raw, **operation_config)
     85 if response.status_code not in [200]:
---> 86     raise models.ModelErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
     88 deserialized = None

ModelErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 14
     11 inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py', environment=myenv)
     13 # Recupera el modelo entrenado
---> 14 model = Model(ws, id='azureml://locations/switzerlandnorth/workspaces/a1797bf8-77a0-43f6-87a9-b0e1dc442ed0/models/titanic_model/versions/1')
     17 # Despliega el servicio web
     18 service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws, name='titanic-service', models=[model], inference_config=inference_config, deployment_config=aciconfig)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py:321, in Model.__init__(self, workspace, name, id, tags, properties, version, run_id, model_framework, expand, **kwargs)
    319     self._initialize(workspace, model_dto=_model_dto, expand=expand)
    320 elif workspace:
--> 321     model_dto = self._get(workspace, name, id, tags, properties, version, model_framework, run_id)
    322     if model_dto:
    323         self._initialize(workspace, model_dto=model_dto, expand=expand)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py:477, in Model._get(workspace, name, id, tags, properties, version, model_framework, run_id)
    474 properties_query = None
    476 if id:
--> 477     return models_client.get_by_id(id)
    479 if version:
    480     return models_client.get_by_id(name + ":" + str(version))

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/models_client.py:33, in ModelsClient.error_with_model_id_handling.<locals>.wrapper(self, model_id, *args, **kwargs)
     31     return func(self, model_id, *args, **kwargs)
     32 except ModelErrorResponseException as ex:
---> 33     return ModelsClient.model_error_response_to_webservice_exception(ex, id=model_id)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/models_client.py:114, in ModelsClient.model_error_response_to_webservice_exception(ex, **kwargs)
    110     error_message = populate_model_not_found_details(**kwargs)
    112     raise WebserviceException(error_message, logger=module_logger)
--> 114 raise WebserviceException('Received bad response from Model Management Service:\n'
    115                           'Response Code: {}\n'
    116                           'Correlation: {}\n'
    117                           'Content: {}'.format(ex.error.status_code, ex.error.correlation, ex.error.details),
    118                           logger=module_logger)

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Received bad response from Model Management Service:
Response Code: None
Correlation: None
Content: None
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Received bad response from Model Management Service:\nResponse Code: None\nCorrelation: None\nContent: None"
    }
}
```

And is it not normal, it is a very simple code, I don't know what is wrong (obviously my `score.py` is in a python file separated but in same location), I thought that generate a simple classification model for getting probabilities would be easier...

Does anyone know anything about this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the probabilities value as output from your endpoint, you can use the score.py file from automl job and modify the default method from `predict` to `predict_prob`.
[image]

[image]

With this change, I was able to get required output from the endpoint.
[image]

For detailed sample code you can check this [notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/classification-bank-marketing-all-features/auto-ml-classification-bank-marketing-all-features.ipynb)